# Jquery Isotope to implement data filters

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I'm first time trying to implement data filter for one of my html template using Jquery Isotope plugin.Couldn't get any error in browser console but data filter doesn't work.

Here's my code:
**HTML**

```
<div class="ui-group" style="margin-left: 20%; margin-top: 2%;">
                <h3 class="ui-group__title">Filter</h3>
                <div class="filters button-group js-radio-button-group">
                  <button class="button is-checked" data-filter="*"> All </button>
                  <button class="button" data-filter=".instances"> Instances </button>
                  <button class="button" data-filter=".images"> Images </button>
                  <button class="button" data-filter=".deployments"> Deployments </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="list_of_members">
            {% for instance in user.instances.all %}
                <div class="orders instances" style="margin-bottom: 2%;">
                    <div class="icon-text">
                        <h3>{{ instance.name }}</h3>
                        <p><b><strong style="color: orange">Server :</strong> </b><br>{{ instance.serverFile }} <br></p><br>
                        <p><b><strong style="color: orange">Package.json :</strong> </b><br>{{ instance.jsonPackageFile }}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
            {% for image in user.images.all %}
                <div class="orders  images" style="margin-bottom: 2%;">
                    <div class="icon-text">
                        <h3>{{ image.tagName }}</h3>
                        <p><b><strong style="color: orange">Instance :</strong> </b><br>{{ image.instance }} <br></p><br>
                        <p><b><strong style="color: orange">Created By :</strong> </b><br>{{ image.user.username }}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
```

**Javascript Part after loading Jquery**

```
<script src="{% static 'js/isotope.pkgd.min.js' %}"></script>
<script>
    // Activate isotope with Jquery filter for instances,images and deployments
    $('.list_of_members').isotope({
        itemSelector: '.orders',
        layoutMode: 'fitRows'
    });
    // Isotope click function
    $('.button').click(function(){
        $('.button').removeClass('is-checked');
        $(this).addClass('is-checked');

        var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $('.list_of_members').isotope({
            filter: selector
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

is there any issue in my code or misconfiguration?
help me, please!